# can we display notifcations to user by using action cable in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

**Scenario**
we have user, post, comments models. if any user comments on a post then post owner will be notified by notification.

is it possible through action cable in rails?

- i am using rails version is 6.1

Comment: Yes, that's what action cable was designed for, it listens for changes in real time.

Comment: So how i can do this?

Comment: Well, it's a broad topic but I would recommend an overview first https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html

Comment: Yeah i read it but as a begginer how can i use it for notifcations like user comment on my post then i want notifcation display for it.